# C# 6 null conditional operator check for .Any()?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

In the example shown here ([and on numerous other websites](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6)) with regards to the null-conditional operator, it states that

```
int? first = customers?[0].Orders.Count();
```

can be used to get the count for the first customer. But this statement does not check for the existence of customers in the collection and can throw an index out of range exception.  What should be the correct (preferably single-lined) statement that takes care of checking for the existence of elements?

Comment: guessing, customer? checks if icustomers array is null ot not, which in your case it is not but customers array is empty. so you don't have any elements at index 0

Comment: And Orders? If Orders is NULL goes in error. You must use: int? first = customers?[0].Orders?.Count();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The null conditional operator is intended for **conditionally accessing `null`** but this isn't the issue you're having.

You are trying to **access an empty array**. You can turn that into a case of accessing null with `FirstOrDefault` and use the operator on that:

```
int? first = customers.FirstOrDefault()?.Orders.Count();
```

If the array isn't empty it will operate on the first item, and if it is empty `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` which will be handled by the null conditional operator.

Edit: As w.b mentioned in the comments, if you're looking for another item than the first one you can use `ElementAtOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: and what about Orders being null?

Comment: @Meehow This isn't what OP asked about. But if so.. just use a conditional access operator there.

Comment: Is this Microsoft documentation in error or just incomplete.? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx ?.

Comment: If I instantiate "var customers = new List<Customer>()" (what I would consider the normal way) then the example "Customer first = customers?[0];" throws an "Index was out of range" exception. In order to get that example to work you would have to instantiate with the contrived "List<Token> tokens = null". The examples seem to suggest that any "out of range" exceptions would be handled.

Comment: @WillC no "out of range" exceptions should be handled. Only null reference exceptions. I don't see anything that suggests otherwise in that documentation.

Comment: I'm ok that it still throws an exception, but the documentation would have been more complete if they had pointed out the alternatives. In my case I am using a look-ahead variable which now succinctly short circuits with "ElementAtOrDefault".

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ's [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx), it will yield a singleton `IEnumerable` in case the collection queried is empty:

```
int? first = customers?.DefaultIfEmpty().First().Orders.Count();
```

or if you want to use indexing:

```
int? first = customers?.DefaultIfEmpty().ToArray()[0].Orders.Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you are asking if there's a built-in (or concise) way to protect against `IndexOutOfRangeException`s. The closest you'll get to it would be something like:

```
myArray?.Length > 42 ? myArray[42] : null
```

or as @w.b. mentioned, utilize ElementAtOrDefault:

```
myArray?.ElementAtOrDefault(42)
```

both of those will protect against `NullReferenceException` as well as `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: I would say that `FirstOrDefault` is built-in and concise.

Comment: @l3arnon only if the index you're after is 0. what if it's 42?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez - there's `ElementAtOrDefault`

Comment: @w.b I actually didn't know that extension exists.